# How to update null cells of specific column with mode of that column ? (Sql using Java)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I used the following code to calculate mode of a column:

```
   public void CalcCatValMean(String colName , String tableName){
    Statement st = null;
    String sql = null;
    String mode = null;

    try{

        setConnection();
        st = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        sql = "SELECT " + colName + " , Count(colName) AS Frequency FROM " +   tableName + " GROUP BY " + colName + " HAVING Count(colName) >= ALL (SELECT  Count(colName) FROM " + tableName + " GROUP BY " + colName + " )";
        System.out.println("sql :" + sql);

        ResultSet rset = st.executeQuery(sql);
        CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowset.populate(rset);

        int i = 1;
        while(rowset.next()) {  // check if a result was returned
              mode = rowset.getString(i); // get your result
              System.out.println("mode is : " + mode);
              i++;
            }

        //Clean-up environment
        st.close(); 
        closeConnection();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the weird thing is that its' also calculating "null" as a value & giving output of following column as "null".

- null
- abc
- null
- null
- xyz

What I want to do is to calculate mode of all values of that column except null and then update null cells of that column with calculated mode.

Comment: what is the result of this:   `System.out.println("sql :" + sql);`?

Comment: Where did you get that output?

Comment: You are not passing Colname as parameter in `Count()` aggregate. Try `Count(*)`. Also, I wonder why you need the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Oh thanks sir,,,, actually it was my silly mistake... query is correct but syntax was wrong